# Azure web sites - 500 internal server error (The specified network name is no longer available)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am running a service on Azure web sites using PHP. From times to times, the server completely stops responding with a 500 HTTP message. So far, I could get these relevant details on the error:

ModuleName: FastCgiModule
Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
HttpStatus: 500
HttpReason: Internal Server Error
HttpSubStatus: 0
ErrorCode: The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040)
ConfigExceptionInfo:

The only info I was able to find was that this might be a prevention of DoS attack when the server stops executing the scripts (for some limited time?). I solve this now by restarting the server which is not good at all.

As I am unable to find an exact cause of this, I am looking for a better solution than manual restarting or even a hint on how to debug the problem. Thanks

Comment: I think you will get better information by contacting windows azure technical support as they have access to your azure instance and backend details which we do not have..

Comment: Support link: http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=mscom or http://support.microsoft.com/get-support/more/